# vXML.Active := True => EDOMParseError at “%25” char sequence

Tags: delphi, txmldocument

I have this problem in Delphi when I want to load an XML file that contains a "%25" in it's file name..

```
   vXML := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  vXML.FileName := pFileName;
  try
    try
      vXML.Active := True;
```

In debug mode there's an error in line

```
vXML.Active := True;
```

Error:

> First chance exception at $75ACC41F. Exception class EDOMParseError
>   with message
>
> Line: 0 '.

Enyone knows how to make TXMLDocument open a file with the "%25" chars in it's file name?

The file is not empty - I checked it.
When I delete the "%25" chars everything is working fine.
Sample file name: "something %25.xml"

My system and IDE:
Windows 7 Home Premium with service pack 1; 
Delphi 2010;

Comment: "EDOMParseError with message." - what message?

Comment: Smells like the library is doing URL decode on the filename which would be, well, odd.

Comment: @David, it is odd, but not that much for the [`IXMLDOMDocument::load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd874126(v=vs.85).aspx) method where this problem falls down. Jack, you can workaround it by using path like `file://C:\Wherever\File %25.xml`. The method which parses the file name most probably treat it as an URL and decode it as such.

Comment: @TLama I don't see why that would turn off URL encoding

Comment: @Jack Ttry to URL encode the filename before passing it the Load method

Comment: @David, you mean turn on, don't you ? You don't want URL decoding for file path. Better to ask, why it doesn't default to that WMS File Data Source plug-in if there is no URL prefix specified. Jack, adding `file://` URL prefix worked for me...

Comment: @TLama I meant turn off URL decoding

Comment: @David, now I see that note. Well, from what I've tried, if you don't specify any prefix, [`the method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd874126(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to take that parameter as URL (decode it and fail). If you explicitly specify the `file://` prefix, it takes it as a file path. I know, documentation says something different. It should default to file path if you don't specify any prefix, but maybe they've added some "intelligence" for that parameter parsing, which then forgot to mention in docs. Or maybe I'm just lucky...

Answer (score 0):

To correctly load a file with (for example) "%25"  in it's file name, we must use PathEncode on the file path. For example:

```
uses idURI;

[...]

vXML.LoadFromFile(TIdURI.PathEncode(pFileName));
```

WARNING: If you use chars that are e.g. 'ó' THIS WON'T WORK...

Comment: It's not just `%25`. This presumably applies much more widely. FWIW, your code in the answer is not right. You ignore the value returned from the call to `Format`. I'd just write it like this: `vEncodedPath:= TIdURI.PathEncode('file://'+pFileName);`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tested this, and.. the 'file://' sequence isn't necessary. You need this if you use URLEncode. If I use URLEnocde and 'file://' it says that it can't find the path. And.. if there are chars like e.g. 'ó' in the file name.. then again it crashes.